# tabs value change in url (edit url hash value), onRendered does not trigger in meteor Blaze FlowRouter

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, javascript-framework, flow-router

I want to get the URL # value after editing the URL link and press keyboard Enter button. 
(Environment:- Meteor, Blaze, FowRouter).

from
  http://localhost:3000/api/information#feedback
to 
http://localhost:3000/api/information#reviews

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain you can get the hash from flow router for the url. Although Flow-Router might not give it straight to you, you could parse the url for it.

You could access it in `Meteor.startup()` for instance.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    console.log(FlowRouter.current());
});
```